# google maps v3 convert address to latitude

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm simply trying to convert a form field from street address => lat/long.
Ideally, the user enters in either a zipcode or a full street address and a hidden field gets populated with the corresponding latitude/longitude.
No map creation needed.
No directions needed.
Just a simple conversion.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Google Maps Geocoding web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).  However, note that per the terms of service, you must display the results on a Google Map.

If you want to use JavaScript, you can use the [Google Maps API Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

Answer (score 1):

There's an API called [LiveAddress](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) by [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) that's really easy to hook into, which will not only geocode the address but also verify that it is correct and complete. It's an easy REST endpoint with JSON output, so it's easy to use with [Javascript](https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/blob/master/jQuery/street-address.html), [PHP](https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/blob/master/php/get.php), etc. (It can actually support thousands of addresses per second, with up to 100 addresses per request.)

As Andres mentioned, you're required to show a Google Map when using their service to obtain lat/lon. There are other APIs which don't have that restriction, but most of them won't verify the address actually exists (such as Google, which only approximates) and they will often have low usage limits.

An API like LiveAddress will only return results for valid addresses and will return close matches *if* they are real, and doesn't have license restrictions which would prevent you from using it in your particular case.

I'm one of the developers at SmartyStreets and so I'm happy to help you out with any further questions about working with addresses.

*By the way, here's a little not-yet-well-known-secret: you can actually submit the address as a single line (meaning you only need one field in your form instead of 4 or 5) and you will still get valid results. Here's an example of that with [jQuery](https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/blob/master/jQuery/slap.html) and [PHP](https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/blob/master/php/slap.php).*

Comment: Hey Matt, that's great info. We'll be hitting whatever API is used quite hard so the bandwidth is a concern as well. I did come up with a quasi-solution using the Google API, but I think it'll fail in production...

Comment: Here's what I had come up with:
`<script>
  function convertAddress() {
 var geocoder;
 var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        document.getElementById('latlong').value = (results[0].geometry.location);
      }
      else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>`

Comment: WOW! that got garbled!
Here it is on Pastie: http://paste2.org/p/2051417
@Matt...So what would be the equivalent to that using LiveAddress?

Comment: Sure. I whipped this up today, just for you. Include [this file](https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/blob/master/javascript/liveaddress.js) in your HTML page, then [use something like this](https://gist.github.com/2921633). Much simpler. Note that we only verify street addresses (not merely city/state) -- but it's on our roadmap to support that.